# Validation of transfer function

Tags: motors

I have developed a second order transfer function model for a permanent magnet dc motor in terms of speed and voltage. I had performed open loop no load experiments on the dc motor and derived the parameters. When I experimentally apply a 12 V to the dc motor the speed that I get does not match with the simulation results obtained from the developed model. How do one validate the open loop transfer function model? Should I use the loaded condition values of voltage and speed for validation

Comment: Is the transfer function developed valid for no load state?

Comment: What model did you construct? Because maybe at 'high' speeds the motor might not behave as a linear (time invariant) system. And what kind of open loop experiments did you perform?

Comment: I used the second order transfer function model of dc motor seen in any control text books. The no load test of dc motor was performed.. Manually the applied voltage was varied and speed was noted